# MustacheException: No method or field with name 'Id' on line 15. Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, intellij-idea, mustache

I'm using MySQL Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64).
Open-JDK 1.8.0
Spring Boot 2.1.4 RELEASE

Accessing my application I got this stacktrace on my whitelable page:

```
 This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
 this as a fallback.

Mon May 27 16:12:06 AZOST 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No method or field with name 'id' on line 15
com.samskivert.mustache.MustacheException$Context: No method or field 
with name 'id' on line 15
at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.checkForMissing(Template.java:326)
at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.getValue(Template.java:234)
at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.getValueOrDefault(Template.java:279)
at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$VariableSegment.execute(Mustache.java:802)
at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$BlockSegment.executeSegs(Mustache.java:845)
at com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache$SectionSegment.execute(Mustache.java:881)
at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.executeSegs(Template.java:157)
at com.samskivert.mustache.Template.execute(Template.java:134)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.view.MustacheView.renderMergedTemplateModel(MustacheView.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(AbstractTemplateView.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:834)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

This is my code:

main.mustache

```
<html>

<body>
<div>
    <form method="POST">
        <input type ="text" name="text" placeholder="Введите сообщение" />
        <input type ="text" name="tag" placeholder="Тег"/>
        <button type="submit">Добавить</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div>Message list</div>
{{#messages}}
<div>
<b>{{id}}</b>
<span>{{text}}</span>
<i>{{tag}}</i>
</div>
{{/messages}}
```

This is my Controller:

GreetingController

```
package com.example.sweater;

import com.example.sweater.domain.Message;
import com.example.sweater.repos.MessageRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class GreetingsController {

@Autowired
private MessageRepo messageRepo;

@RequestMapping("/greeting")
public String greeting(@RequestParam(name="name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name,
                       Map<String, Object> model)
{
    model.put("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}
@GetMapping
public String main(Map<String, Object> model){
    Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
    model.put("messages", "messages");
    return "main";
}
@PostMapping
public String add(@RequestParam String text, @RequestParam String tag, Map<String, Object> model){
    Message message = new Message(text, tag);
    messageRepo.save(message);
    Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
    model.put("messages", messages);
    return "main";
}
```

}

This is my project structure:
![ProjectStructure]: (https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/PKENYsmd29WxawAs-jMtrwBTBqDHNMoS3LWU_BTyDOjO7L5z8DrojsmB-pHfb03QE2Ce7Q3_xE4HrMk3PZax06Cd2b-NY42pB9e5DzCv-Uh6VlkbtebFb2W0HYq8u7WaG7WWU7uC7_7z5x8TXTXl65Wg-rMCes6HkQ8PTQ2_-QOMBW_I2yV8dXN2Xs2-vsHAWX5upPKw2oi3ZAtxOVvDKUm-znDD4czMIPAMKsDAfBXWWf5QbVpTysOEoE_rF7_7z9lWBf0ujZBYpllK5aXxsWB0OorsnnLb9XvmCMaGU-3xsOykLRFiq_LcYk5erFkEsBSkkobYT67ZPIPxrcnC3iGluBy5IYjDUrhwVpn-WPv76RsEID0qF0PYrAGO01M1Xb0QzhOJjx0wKsIKIDBRSEfxSRSLp-rGVW0rsDF_VIQeRXLs-Bvt45LznMXIBjCH_OLA3sg5p7RsgmiiRrjtsFhKmH-GOUds1GvrUTfpdpjlcySm_vpYK84WhyGfc64As45xB04w62mkD0LgZpw9pFcENbp8l9_MNhRlh0dLccB0Tku5H9h1-9H4FD3OzHYlw6SlsoNfYob_7BeZK3QXaTujtu1K7Hn-5zaxJ_oI4Ea_4P59BSmzAp6X_D6O0Rs9rZ8zPtSPNHiBzB6SP_vOuCfMuOAa8w=w340-h520-no)

I expected this code to display HTML code with empty fields waiting for me to fill in them, access the database and show all tuples which was typed into empty fields, but instead I ran into this stacktrace. What should i fix to make it work correctly?

Comment: The link you have provided for the project structure is broken and not visible please update it. Check whether you have kept your templates under src/main/resources/templates folder.

Answer (score 0):

From your stack trace it can be seen that you are passing `messages` to be iterated in the template :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No method or field with name 'id' on line 15
```

But the messages model being returned from the controller might be missing 'id' values . If we didn’t assign a value to a {{id}} on the Mustache’s page, the jmustache will throw the above error message.Can you please check if the data returned from the main method is returning correctly.Or mark the value as optional in the template.

If not check the following :
Ensure that you have configured mustache properly.Ensure that you have the following dependency added in pom :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Also ensure that all your dynamic html content is kept in the directory :

```
src/main/resources/templates/
```

folder so that spring will take it up.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping
public String main(Map<String, Object> model){
    Iterable<Message> messages = messageRepo.findAll();
    model.put("messages", "messages");
    return "main";
}
```

change to

```
model.put("messages", messages);
```